# Customizing biblatex "alphabetic" style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex

I'm trying to customize my citation a little, but don't know how to achieve my goals.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
fleqn,                                          
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,BCOR=25mm,
english,
DIV = 12
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@online{test,
url = {http://test.test},
urldate = {2018-12-15},
title = {Test Bib},
label = {TB}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\bibliography{mybib}
\begin{document}
This is the first example\autocite{test}.\\
This is the second example\footfullcite{test}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My Goal is to combine the "footnotes" of the first example in brackets and the second example, such that it prints (the 1 should be subscripted):

1 [TB] *Test Bib*. `URL: http://test.test` (visited on 12/15/2018)

For compiling I'm using LuaLaTex,

Best, cortesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new `\cite...` command based on `\footfullcite` that also prints the alphabetic label

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,BCOR=25mm,
  english,
  DIV = 12
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitewithalphalabel}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
     \printfield{labelalpha}%
     \printfield{extraalpha}}%
   \printunit{\addspace}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{test,
url = {http://test.test},
urldate = {2018-12-15},
title = {Test Bib},
label = {TB}
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is the first example\autocite{test}.

This is the second example\footfullcitewithalphalabel{test}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [TB] Test Bib. url: http://test.test (visited on 12/15/2018).]

I personally think that an `alphabetic` bibstyle does not really lend itself to footnote citations. Like `numeric` labels `alphabetic` labels are intended for use in the text directly, that's why they are reasonably short and compact. Indeed, since each footnote starts in a new line, you may end up wasting more space when you use `alphabetic` in footnotes rather than inline.